# How to add Redis environmental variables in virtual event starter kit by vercel (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, redis, next.js, redis-cluster

I just started next.js and javascript as a whole. I am stuck in a problem, that if anyone explains would be cool. So, I started using the [virtual event starter kit](https://github.com/vercel/virtual-event-starter-kit) template in vercel which is made using NextJS. I was able to set up everything, except the redis (Upstash) part. I am not sure on how to set it up, if anyone could go through the docs and explain me would be really cool

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to set up Redis for this project, or only how to specify the environment variables?

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky both actually